# Authorisation check in controller - Scala/Play

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

This is a simple example of a controller in Play Framework where every action checks the session - if the user is logged in.

```
object Application extends Controller {

    def index = Action { implicit request =>
        if (request.session.isEmpty) {
            Redirect("/login")
        } else {
            Ok(views.html.index("index"))
        }
    }

    def about = Action { implicit request =>
        if (request.session.isEmpty) {
            Redirect("/login")
        } else {
            Ok(views.html.index("about"))
        }
    }

}
```

I'd like to handle the session checking in the constructor instead of every action method, but I just don't know how? It should look something like this:

```
object Application extends Controller {

    //This is where the constructor would check if session exists
    //and if not - redirect to login screen

    def index = Action {
        Ok(views.html.index("index"))
    }

    def about = Action {
        Ok(views.html.index("about"))
    }

}
```

Is this possible and if so then how?

My stack is Play Framework 2.2.1, Scala 2.10.3, Java 1.8.0-ea 64bit

**UPDATE - SOLVED** Thanks for all your ideas, solution is now found, see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution is to use Action Composition and create a custom action.

Auth.scala:

```
package core

import play.api.mvc._
import scala.concurrent._
import play.api.mvc.Results._

object AuthAction extends ActionBuilder[Request] {

    def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (Request[A]) => Future[SimpleResult]) = {
        if (request.session.isEmpty) {
            //authentication condition not met - redirect to login page
            Future.successful(Redirect("/login"))
        } else {
            //proceed with action as normal
            block(request)
        }
    }

}
```

Application.scala:

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import core._

object Application extends Controller {

    def index = AuthAction {
        Ok(views.html.index("You are logged in."))
    }

}
```

Comment: But ActionBuilder is not a generic.

Answer (score 9):

You could take advantage of [Action Composition](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/ScalaActionsComposition) to achieve this. From the documentation:

```
import play.api.mvc._

class AuthenticatedRequest[A](val username: String, request: Request[A]) extend WrappedRequest[A](request)

object Authenticated extends ActionBuilder[AuthenticatedRequest] {
  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (AuthenticatedRequest[A]) =>Future[SimpleResult]) = {
    request.session.get("username").map { username =>
      block(new AuthenticatedRequest(username, request))
    } getOrElse {
      Future.successful(Forbidden)
    }
  }
}
```

And then you could simply do:

```
def index = Authenticated {
    Ok(views.html.index("index"))
}
```

Alternatively you could set up a filter instead (as @Robin Green suggested) like so:

```
object AuthFilter extends Filter {

  override def apply(next: RequestHeader => Result)(rh: RequestHeader): Result = {
    rh.session.get("username").map { user =>
      next(rh)
  }.getOrElse {
    Redirect("/login")
  }
}
```

In Global.scala scala, add

```
override def doFilter(action: EssentialAction) = AuthFilter(action)
```

For more on Filters, see the official [docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/ScalaHttpFilters)

Comment: Thanks, I was already looking into Action Composition for a few hours now and just stumbled on a rather simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Deadbolt: https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2 . There are exhaustive examples and guides.

Works perfectly in my Play 2 project.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Filter`, which applies to every request in the application. However, then you would need to have some code in that `Filter` to allow certain URLs to be accessed without a valid session, otherwise then the user would not be able to login in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - it makes sense, although I'm having trouble finding a good example on how to use filter on specifically play controller object.